# Sequelize transaction does not rollback when exception throws

Tags: node.js, transactions, sequelize.js

I want to implement transcation in sequelize. But After Applying transaction Code does not roll back currently inserted row. Can some assist me what i am doing wrong? Package.json version is "sequelize": "^4.39.0","sequelize-cli": "^3.2.0",

```
 let sequelize = model.sequelize;
    return sequelize.transaction().then(function (t) {
        return model.error_logs.create(
            error_logs, { transaction: t }).then(function (user) {
            error_logs.stack = 'For Checking Transcation'
            return models.error_logs.create(error_logs, { transaction: t }); <-- Here I am creating expection
        }).then(function () {
            t.commit();
        }).catch(function (err) {
            t.rollback();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should await each operation in transaction before each other and before a transaction ends like this:

```
const transaction = await sequelize.transaction()
try {
  const newLog = await model.error_logs.create(error_logs, { transaction: transaction })
  error_logs.stack = 'For Checking Transcation'
  const anotherNewLog = await model.error_logs.create(error_logs, { transaction: transaction })
  await transaction.commit()
} catch (err) {
  await transaction.rollback()
}
```

Solution 2:

```
const transaction = await sequelize.transaction(async transaction => {
  const newLog = await model.error_logs.create(error_logs, { transaction: transaction })
  error_logs.stack = 'For Checking Transcation'
  const anotherNewLog = await model.error_logs.create(error_logs, { transaction: transaction })
})
```

Comment: No success, Is there is problem with this version of sequelize ?

Comment: Maybe both `create` calls finished successfully? Did you check that by setting a breakpoint on `transaction.commit()` or even in a DB?

Comment: Yes checked on DB  , what actually happens is that when exception throwing code i-e 2nd create statement runs it goes catch block and rollback is executed but when I checks on DB 1st created statement successfully committed . But it should be rolled back b/c i am using transaction

Comment: Please edit and remove `await model.error_logs.create(error_logs, { transaction: transaction })` await in create statement will cause exception. Putting `async` before lamda expression  resolves error but Transaction does not rolled back.

Comment: try to output to console both created items just after each `create` call